# Unable to add API access entry

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have created three B2C applications:

- TestWebApp
- TestApiOne
- TestApiTwo

Both API applications were created the exact same way. Web API access is enabled, reply URLs have been specified, an App ID URL has been assigned, and keys have been generated. Both APIs have an additional read and write scope.

In TestWebApp API access, I am able to add TestApiOne with all three scopes without an issue.

When trying to add TestApiTwo to the TestWebApp API access list, the operation fails with the following error.

> Failed to add the API access. Reason: The B2C service has an internal
>   error. If you created this B2C directory just now, please try again
>   after couple of minutes. If the problem persists, please contact
>   Support
>   (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-support/).
>   If you do not have a B2C directory you can refer
>   https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/active-directory-b2c-get-started/

I thought maybe there is a limit of one API per application. To test, I created a temporary application "TempApp". I received the same error displayed above while trying to add API access for both TestApiOne and TestApiTwo.

Has anyone else experienced this issue?

Comment: The App ID URLs for each API app aren't the same value are they?

Comment: I have verified the URLs are unique for all applications in the directory.

Answer (score 0):

There's not a limit of one API per application. I have done research and it works fine by my side.
[image]

Please have a look at the [guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-app-registration) and check your steps.

Comment: I have followed this guide exactly and I still have the same error. I have opened a ticket with Microsoft to investigate.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to replicate the issues that you are facing by putting diff redirect reply url domains and also by making one application to be native and one normal web app but it doesn't help.

Could you try to delete all the webapps and try making 1 and then adding another to it.
Then create the 3rd one.

Please check this or if you can share some screen shots. That would be helpful.

**You can definitely add multiple web apps to api access of one web app.**